# Evaluate macro depending if another macro is defined

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

The following preprocessor-based identifier-to-string lookup table:

```
#include <iostream>

// included generated file
#define KEY_a valueA
#define KEY_b valueB
///////

#define LOOKUP_(_key_) KEY_ ## _key_
#define QUOTE_(_str_) #_str_
#define EXPAND_AND_QUOTE_(_str_) QUOTE_(_str_)

#define LOOKUP(_key_) EXPAND_AND_QUOTE_(LOOKUP_(_key_))

int main() {
    std::cout << LOOKUP(a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << LOOKUP(b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << LOOKUP(c) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
valueA
valueB
KEY_c
```

The first #defines come from an #included header generated by an external script before the compilation.

The `LOOKUP` macro correctly handles existing key in the table, and substitutes the given value as string literal.

But for non-existing keys, it substitutes the key as string literal.

Is there a way to instead make it substitute a given constant for non-existing keys, without causing a compile-time error, and all within the preprocessing stage?

So for example, the `LOOKUP(c)` and `LOOKUP(whatever)` should all be substituted to `"undefined"`, without `c` or `whatever` occuring in the included generated file.

The names of the keys should not be outputted to the compiled binary, so ideally they should never be seen by the compiler.

Comment: `#ifdef`,`#ifndef`,`#else` you can say `#ifdef DEFINITION` to check if something has been declared using `#define`

Comment: If should work without adding additional code at the place where the `LOOKUP()` macro is called. `#if` etc cannot be put inside macro expansions

Comment: Can you alter the definitions of `KEY_*`?

Comment: Yes the #defines are generated by a script which can be changed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple, if hacky, solution. By making the definition of `KEY_x` a list of two elements (the first of which will be ignored), it permits adding a default value:

```
#include <iostream>

// included generated file
#define KEY_a _,valueA
#define KEY_b _,valueB
///////

#define LOOKUP_(key) KEY_ ## key
#define QUOTE_(_,str,...) #str
#define EXPAND_AND_QUOTE_(...) QUOTE_(__VA_ARGS__)

#define LOOKUP(key) EXPAND_AND_QUOTE_(LOOKUP_(key),undefined)

int main() {
    std::cout << LOOKUP(a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << LOOKUP(b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << LOOKUP(c) << std::endl;
}
```

Test on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c01190196415ff28)